# Flutter app deploy rejected by Google because of brocken functionality

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

Certainly, my friend. Here's a revised version of your message:

Hello everyone,

I recently encountered an issue where my Flutter application was rejected by Google Play due to malfunctioning features. It was quite perplexing, as the rejection notice mentioned that the app installs successfully but fails to load. However, when I tested the same code locally using `flutter run --release` across multiple devices, I couldn't replicate the loading issue. Interestingly, the iOS version of the app was published without any issues. Has anyone faced similar challenges, and how can I guarantee that my app passes the loading test?